# magento 2.2.7 configurable products don't show up shipment address in checkout

Tags: checkout, magento2.2, configurable-product

**when configure product's child product purchase at time shipping address missing in checkout**

[image]

> my database side `catalog_product_entity` table

[image]

> 1.when i run `reindex` command then 2-3 days working fine after same
>   issue is coming 
>   2.if child product add **weight** then working good

Comment: what shipping method are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 needs weight value for a product to be considered shippable, if you are importing that csv file, check the imported products and make sure the ones supposed to be "simple" are not created as "virtual"

Comment: thanks for replay but weight add is not solution  and i have checked my all products is simple and configure

Comment: if adding weight is not a possibility for your products you will probably have to find and override the method checking those details in checkout

Comment: this type condition available in my block file 

    if ($this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->isVirtual()) {
                    $layout = 'virtual';
                } else {
                    $layout = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('amasty_checkout/design/layout', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
                }

Comment: if you are not selling virtual products you can try removing the isVirtual condition check

Comment: My store is live if any problem i will remove it because many order creates

Answer (score 0):

If in your condition virtual product is associated to configurable product that time shipping address is skip into the checkout.
Please check your associated product list with your configurable product.

Comment: thanks for replay but weight add is not solution

Answer (score 0):

Please try it by giving a static weight for all products like 0.1 weight for all products by using script.
**1)** If you want to do it by database then here is the code:

```
select * from eav_attribute where attribute_code='weight'; it will give you id of that attribute

select * from catalog_product_entity_decimal where attribute_id=82 // find that attribute value

update catalog_product_entity_decimal set value='' where attribute_id=82 and value='0.3'
```

**2)** If you want to do it when product save:
Create this event `catalog_product_save_after` and load product and update its weight.
This event run everytime after product save.

**3)** Create a script to do this.

**This is the temporary solution. Hope it works!!**

Comment: i know this solution but it is temporary solution not permanent

Comment: @RakeshDonga if you follow step 2 , then this solution will work always.

Comment: no this is one type temporary solution